# How to get the data in between two strings in a html page

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I have few html pages which look like this:

Heading

Introduction

Table of contents:

option1. Art

option2. Sports

option3. Dance

Instructions to choose

option1. Art

a. water colors
   description
b. Oil painting
   description
c. acrylic painting
   description

option2. Sports

a. Basket Ball
   description
b. Cricket
   description
c. Foot ball
   description

option3. Dance

a. Break dance

All of this content is kept in different html formats in each html page. I want to collect the entire text under the sports option in each page. (Is there anyway that I can achieve this other than figuring out the xpaths because structure of each html page is different).

Please help. Thank you.

Sample html:

```
<Document>
<TYPE>
<SEQUENCE>
<FILENAME>
<DESCRIPTION>
<TEXT>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 1. Art history: </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The nature of art has been described by philosopher Richard Wollheim as "one of the most elusive of the traditional problems of human culture".[19] Art has been defined as a vehicle for the expression or communication of emotions and ideas </FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 2. Sports division : </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hundreds of sports exist, from those between single contestants, through to those with hundreds of simultaneous participants, either in teams or competing as individuals. In certain sports such as racing, many contestants may compete, simultaneously or consecutively, with one winner; in others, the contest (a match) is between two sides, each attempting to exceed the other.</FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 3. Dance group: </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;An important distinction is to be drawn between the contexts of theatrical and participatory dance,[4] although these two categories are not always completely separate; both may have special functions, </FONT></P>
```

Comment: `<div section="sports".*?/>(.*)<div section="Dance"` <- if you have section headers it's easy to use a regex to get this.  Although the actual HTML might be useful info to provide here...

Comment: Hi, I have provided the sample html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd make use of jQuery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) here, as it seems to do exactly what you want (shows only text content of all selected nodes).

Other than that, it's a simple matter of selecting the right elements, so we do need to know what "section" to select. Maybe something like:

`$("P:contains('option 2')").nextUntil("p:contains('option 3')").text()`

```js
console.log($("P:contains('option 2')").nextUntil("p:contains('option 3')").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scott">
<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 1. Art history: </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The nature of art has been described by philosopher Richard Wollheim as "one of the most elusive of the traditional problems of human culture".[19] Art has been defined as a vehicle for the expression or communication of emotions and ideas </FONT></P>



<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 2. Sports division : </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hundreds of sports exist, from those between single contestants, through to those with hundreds of simultaneous participants, either in teams or competing as individuals. In certain sports such as racing, many contestants may compete, simultaneously or consecutively, with one winner; in others, the contest (a match) is between two sides, each attempting to exceed the other.</FONT></P>

<div>some other random stuff here.</div>

<P style="font-family:times;;margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;"><FONT SIZE=2><B>

<!-- COMMAND=STYLE_ADDED,"margin-left:10.0pt;text-indent:-10.0pt;" -->

option 3. Dance group: </B></FONT></P>

<P style="font-family:times;"><FONT SIZE=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;An important distinction is to be drawn between the contexts of theatrical and participatory dance,[4] although these two categories are not always completely separate; both may have special functions, </FONT></P>

</div>
```